# How do I compute the spread of ROC curves?

Tags: variance, cross-validation, mean, roc, model-evaluation

I want to say that my statistic background is very poor,  but I'm doing Machine Learning, so I need to learn a bit of it. (my experiment may not make sense. If not, please suggest)

Let's say I've got ROC curves, like in the pictures, representing the performance of 2 classifiers evaluated via cross-validation. I want to measure how stable the models are (i.e. if/how performance changes based on the training set).

For example, there is more spread in the second plot than in the first.

1) Is it a good metric to compute the area between the curves?

2) If not, how can I tell that the first model is better than the second? (is it?)

**cross-validation first classifier -- little spread**
[image]

**cross-validation second classifier -- more spread**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as detailed [here](http://www.fharrell.com/2017/01/classification-vs-prediction.html) you cannot get ROC curves from a classifier because a classifier is a 0-1 output.  So you must not really be using a classifier but rather a probability estimator.  Those who haven't taken many statistical courses often confuse 'classifier' with having a discrete dependent variable.  The two are vastly different concepts.  Next you must ensure that cross-validation (you need about 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation to get sufficient precision, or several hundred bootstrap resamples) repeated all steps of the analysis (including any feature selection not masked to $Y$) afresh or all of your estimates will be biased.  Then you get a single concordance probability (c-index; AUROC) and don't look so much at the individual concordance probabilities/ROC curves.

c-index (AUROC) is not a very sensitive measure so consider the use of proper scoring rules as discussed in [here](http://www.fharrell.com/2017/03/damage-caused-by-classification.html).

Comment: OK, the output of my model is a vector of probabilities, so it's a probability estimator as you said (sorry for confusing). I use a convolutional neural network, so I don't consider features because it learns by itself. Also, I can create a single ROC curve from all the scores I got from cross-validation. What I would like to know, is how I can use the above plots in any meaningful way. Any ideas?

Comment: That neural network approach is effectively a regression model with lots of interaction terms and is prone to overfitting.  To cross-validate you must restart the neural network **from scratch** with resampling methods (cross-val or bootstrap) then use standard techniques to get overfitting-corrected index of model performance (Brier score, pseudo $R^2$, c-index, etc.).